# Excel scientific notation exponent format

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am making a plot in Excel that will be published professionally.  I have a log plot with the axes labeled 1E0, 1E-1, 1E-2, etc.  But for display purposes I would much prefer the number format to be

10, 10^-1, 10^-2, i.e.

[image: file]

Is there a way to do this?  Thank you.

Follow up question: is there a way to add a secondary set of units to a single axis, i.e.:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, Excel only uses the E+/E- format for scientific notation. However, you can create your Excel graph and paste it into another application (e.g. PowerPoint) as EMF, and manipulate the number format there.

Same applies to your second question: you can add a secondary axis, but it will always be on the righthand side of the graph. After pasting it as EMF and ungrouping, you can move the stack of labels to the left.

Answer (score 1):

To display powers of 10 as in mathematical notation, you need to prepare a set of such text labels and display them instead of the standard numeric labels on the y-axis. For this you need to add to the chart an additional data series with x = 0 and the values y you want to have on the labels.
The procedure is described elsewhere.
[How to create a text based Y axis on excel chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300014/how-to-create-a-text-based-y-axis-on-excel-chart)
[Chart Axis - Use Text Instead of Numbers - Excel & Google Sheets - Automate Excel](https://www.automateexcel.com/charts/axis-text/)
The labels themselves should be prepared using Unicode characters corresponding to the superscript character `-` and the digits. For example, such VBA code can be used.

```
Sub SuperScript()
    ' generating labels for Y axis
    Dim start As Range
    Set start = ActiveCell
    Dim ex As Long, ex0 As Long, exf As Long, m As String, upd As String
    ex0 = 2 'upper limit
    exf = -6  'bottom limit
    For ex = ex0 To exf Step -1
       If ex < 0 Then m = ChrW(&H207B) Else m = vbNullString
       Select Case Abs(ex)
          Case 1: upd = ChrW(&HB9)
          Case 2: upd = ChrW(&HB2)
          Case 3: upd = ChrW(&HB3)
          Case 0, 4 To 9: upd = ChrW(&H2070 + Abs(ex))
       End Select
       start.Offset(ex0 - ex).Value = "10" & m & upd
    Next ex
End Sub
```

Sample chart
[image: Scientific labels on Y axis]

Answer (score 1):

For your secondary requirement you could try "cheating":

- remove all the axis labels (or use a custom number format so they are invisible)
- build a dummy data series with as many points as you want labels for, one for each axis. One would have x=0 for every point to replace the vertical axis, one would have y=0 for every point to replace the horizontal. The other values would (probably) be at each order of magnitude ie 0.1, 1, 10 etc
- type a series of labels to use which show the numbers in both formats, and sort out the whitespace between them. eg a label might be

  ```
  10 (100)
  ```

or

```
    1  (10)
```

(note the spacing to make the second half line up)

- you might be able to use carriage returns for the x-axis labels to force the line wrapping
- Add these series so they are drawn where the axes were. Format to show no visible line or markers. Add data labels.
- In the data labels formatting, you can tell it to show a list of labels which are independent of the values themselves

Aside: if this were a categorical horizontal axis instead of value-based, you could use stacked categories for that one, like you will often see for years and months, or category / subcategory eg:

```
Oct   Nov   Dec   Jan   Feb   Mar
2022              2023
```